# C# Query Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, servicecontroller

I have been using an application that queries Windows Services running on remote servers and writes the Machine Name, Service Name, and Status to a database.

However, I want to try and capture the startup type (Automatic, Manual, Disabled) as well.  I was using a Service Controller which does not have any options for startup type so I started looking at using a Management Class.  This class looks like it has everything I need but I don't know how to use it against my remotes servers.  For the Service Controller, I was doing this:

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(serverIP);

foreach (ServiceController service in services)
{
   var machine = service.MachineName;
   var displayName = service.DisplayName;
   var status = service.Status;
}
```

I tried this for the Management class:

```
ManagementClass class1 = new ManagementClass(serverIP + "\\" + "Win32_Service");

foreach (ManagementObject ob in class1.GetInstances())
{
   var machine = serverIP;
   var displayName = ob.GetPropertyValue("Description");
   var name = ob.GetPropertyValue("PathName");
   var startMode = ob.GetPropertyValue("StartMode");
   var status = ob.GetPropertyValue("State");
}
```

But of course it didn't work.  Anyone know how I can get the Services from a remote machine using the Management Class?  Or is there another way using the Service Controller to get the startup type?

I also tried to combine them both and put the Management Class foreach statement inside the Service Controller but it got stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: I think I got it by doing this: (@"\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Service").  I will keep testing because now I can't find the Property for Service Name.

Comment: Your fix makes sense; you always refer to remote computers as \\computername, and without the @ sign C# things you're escaping a single backslash.

Comment: If anyone is wondering the Property for Service Name is just Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code above worked.  Just add this to Management Class

```
(@"\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Service")
```

Answer (score 1):

The information you're looking for is available in WMI.

It will be MUCH easier to write this whole thing in PowerShell than in Pure C#.  WMI code gets very messy in C# (or C++, or VBScript), very quickly.  This snippet demostrates getting the data from a list of computers.  To embed in C#, simply use System.Management.Automation, and add PowerShell.Create().AddScript(...).Invoke()

```
$computerList = "a","b","c"
Get-WmiObject -computerName $computerList -asjob
    | Wait-job
    | receive-job
    | Select-Object DisplayName, Description, StartMode, State
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What if I pull my servers from a table in a database?  I have created a SQL reader which pulls the server IP.  Sorry I left that out of the example.

Comment: Then you'd just populate $computerList from that database.  The SqlClient class in .NET should be what you're looking for.  You can create it New-Object (a few web searches for PowerShell + SQL will send you on the right path).