# Enumerate information of Windows services C# ( see screenshot )

Tags: c#, windows

As in the title of my post, I would like to list information of windows services like service name, its path ,who the service is started by etc.. ( you can look at the screenshot for more information )

Currently with my code, I can extract through the registry key ""HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services""
the name of the service and its path but for the rest I did not succeed in it

[image]

I am not allowed to use automatic solutions like powerUp powershell

I have to do it in c#

Comment: What do you have so far? You could use P/Invoke [QueryServiceConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryserviceconfigw)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Query Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711726/c-sharp-query-windows-service)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Not really ..

Comment: @Charlieface It's for a project, otherwise I would have already used ready-made solutions like PowerUp powershell

Comment: If you have other constrain to a solution you're looking for, you should consider adding "Is it possible/How to ... without/with ..." to your title or inside your content.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I did it thanks